# Clarify the working of add and printNodes functions in this code

Tags: scala, class, generics, types, parameters

In this code I can able to understand the use of X for dynamic type casting. But I can't able to understand how add function really loads the data.

anyone please help me to understand step by step execution of add and printNodes method in detail. Thanks

```
class UsingGenericsForLinkedList[X] {
  private class Node[X](elem: X) {  
    var next: Node[X] = _  
    override def toString = elem.toString  
  }  
  private var head: Node[X] = _  

  def add(elem: X) { //Add element in the linekd list  
    val value = new Node(elem)  
    value.next = head  
    head = value  
  }    

  private def printNodes(value: Node[X]) { // prining value of the nodes  
    if (value != null) {  
      println(value)  
      printNodes(value.next)  
    }  
  }  
  def printAll() { printNodes(head) } //print all the node values at a time  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a (singly) linked list, one maintains cells (here the `Node` class) that carry an element payload and a pointer to the next cell. Here you have a mutable linked list, so the `next` pointers can be updated (are mutable `var`s). The outer structure keeps a pointer to `head`, the first node of the list, which is initially `null` to indicate an empty list. When you traverse, you find the first node in `head`, then do something with its payload (the payload is `elem` in `Node` which is only made available here through `toString`), then repeat the procedure by looking at the `next` pointer, until that becomes `null`.

Note that `add` replaces `head`, and puts the previous value of `head` into the `next` field of the newly inserted node. So technically, this *prepends* an element to the list, it will become the first element to be found. So if you do `add(1), add(2), add(3)`, you get the traversal `3, 2, 1`. This is equivalent to `::` in Scala's default `List` class.

[Here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/writing-immutable-singly-linked-list-in-scala) is a tutorial on Scala's (immutable) List type; the only difference there is that you never replace `next` or `head` pointers, but return a new head cell when you prepend.